# this.Controls returns null

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, forms

There are similar questions to this on here but nothing that answers this specific issue.  I'm creating a button object to dynamically amend the Image on the button.  But using the code below, I get a "Object reference is not set to an instance of an object" when I try and set the Image on the button.

```
Button button3;
button3 = (Button)this.Controls["btnDay" + ctrlsFwd.ToString("00")];
button3.Image = Resources.BookingAllDay;
```

Any help appreciated!  Go easy - it's my first post :-)

** Update - A bit of a facepalm moment.  The buttons are in a panel, so I needed to refer to pnlCalendar.Controls and not this.Controls.

Comment: when are you calling this?

Comment: It's in a switch statement.  In this particular instance, the button name it's trying to resolve is called btnDay05.  This does exist as a Button so I can't see why it returns null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this, `button3 = (Button)this.Controls["btnDay" + ctrlsFwd.ToString("00")];`, is a perfectly valid way of accessing a control, and doesn't work, either a control with that name doesn't exist or more likely the control is inside a container.  Either way searching for it in `this` isn't going to find it no matter how many different ways you try and find it.

Answer (score 5):

One way of doing this would be:

```
button3 = (Button)this.Controls
    .Find("btnDay" + ctrlsFwd.ToString("00"))
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

another way of doing it would be:

```
button3 = this.Controls.OfType<Button>()
    .Where(b => b.Name == "btnDay" + ctrlsFwd.ToString("00"))
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

As pointed out by `Stefan`, check for `null`:

```
if (button3 == null) { return; }
```

because it **can** happen.

Comment: The syntax in the top suggestion returns the error Error Cannot convert type 'System.Windows.Forms.Control[]' to 'System.Windows.Forms.Button'

Comment: @thew00d, sorry about that. Need to call `First` on that too. Actually, I'm going to modify to use `FirstOrDefault()`.

Comment: The LINQ syntax returned Sequence contains no elements.

Comment: @thew00d, yeah that's why I changed it to `FirstOrDefault` so you get a `null` instead. Now, if it can't find the control, that means you don't have one with that name.