# Find a control by name and then pass that control to a method and change a property value from a separate thread

Tags: c#

I have a list of IPs and Hostnames stored in a dictionary. I want to send a ping request, get the success status and run a method that updates the UI.

I use the key and the naming convention of the picture box controls to find the corresponding picture boxes and I'm trying to pass the output to my method that takes in Controls.

Method that contains the ping functionality

```
////////////////
// HEARTBEAT //
//////////////
private async void DodHeartBeat()
{
    // Create ping reply object
    PingReply pingReply;
    // Create ping object
    System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping ping = new();
    // Send ping request
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> ipList in serverIPAddress)
    {
         // Get picture box name
         string greenPictureBoxString = ipList.Key + "_Green_PictureBox";
         string redPictureBoxString = ipList.Key + "_Red_PictureBox";
         // Control

        // Send Ping
        pingReply = ping.Send(ipList.Value);

        if(pingReply.Status.ToString().Contains("Success"))
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Ping to IP: " + ipList.Value + " succesful!");
            UpdateUI(this.Controls[greenPictureBoxString], this.Controls[redPictureBoxString], online_Label, offline_Label);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Ping to IP: " + ipList.Value + " failed!");
            UpdateUI(this.Controls[redPictureBoxString], this.Controls[greenPictureBoxString], online_Label, offline_Label);
        }
    }
}
```

UpdateUI method

```
///////////////////////////////
// UI Updater for Heartbeat //
/////////////////////////////
public static void UpdateUI(Control enable, Control disable, Label labelToShow, Label labelToHide)
{
    (enable as PictureBox).Visible = true;
    labelToShow.Visible = true;
    (disable as PictureBox).Visible = false;
    labelToHide.Visible = false;
}
```

I can see that `this.Controls[redPictureBoxString]` struggles finds the control I'm looking for,`UpdateUI` page returning a `null` value for `Control enable` and `Control disable`. But the name of the control, and the content of the string are the same.

The way I've seen sets the value like `this.Controls[PictureBox].Visible = true`, but I can't change the UI as it's on a seperate thread.

Comment: Why should be the `DodHeartBeat()` method that knows what Controls need to be updated, and not the `UpdateUI()` method? The former should just pass data, maybe also some identifier. BTW, why is `DodHeartBeat()` marked `async` when there's nothing asynchronous there, you're not awaiting anything? It's also `async void`, so double-trouble -- You should probably pass an `IProgress<T>` delegate to `DodHeartBeat()`

Comment: Does this help with the finding of the control? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20073711/this-controls-returns-null

Comment: Controls Property sees only controls directly on that control the property belongs to. If there are other container controls in between you must recurse into the control structure. And yes Controls can only be changed from the thread they belong to presumably the main thread. So you must synchronize into that thread to update controls. Controls have a Invoke method for that if we are talking about winforms.

Comment: @Ralf that was it, the controls were within a TabPage, once I referenced it instead of `this.` it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the static and pass the name of the PictureBoxes. Then you can use the recursive overload of `Controls.Find()`:

```
///////////////////////////////
// UI Updater for Heartbeat //
/////////////////////////////
public void UpdateUI(String enableName, String disableName, Label labelToShow, Label labelToHide)
{
    PictureBox pb = this.Controls.Find(enableName, true).FirstOrDefault() as PictureBox;
    if (pb != null)
    {
        pb.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { 
            pb.Visible = true;
            labelToShow.Visible = true;
        });                
    }
    
    pb = this.Controls.Find(disableName, true).First() as PictureBox;
    if (pb != null)
    {
        pb.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            pb.Visible = false;
            labelToHide.Visible = false;
        });
    }            
}
```